# performance gains using multithreaded raytracing

Tags: c, linux, macos, pthreads, raytracing

I am writing a ray tracer (school project). I've implemented multi-threading by dividing the rendered image into horizontal chunks (y-lines) and having each thread render its own chunk.

Running with 2 threads (vs none or just 1), the performance improvement is only about 20-30% in terms of runtime.

I am confused as to why I am not seeing a more significant speed gains. I am not using any mutexes/locks. Is it possible that there is a contention for FPU unit?

Using C, compiled with gcc and pthreads, tested on osx and ubuntu (in a VM), intel i5 cpu. Also, all my math is done with doubles. My host OS is osx and i wonder if I'm running in "balanced" power-saving mode - vs High-performance (like it can be selected on windows).

Unfortunately I cant post much code - that's against school's academic integrity policies.

This is how Im launching the threads:

```
 //set up threads
 int chunk_size = y_lines/NUM_THREADS;
 for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {

   // setup thread_config[i]

   pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &thread_do_render, (void *) &thread_config[i]);
 }

 /* start threads and wait for them to finish */
 for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
   pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
 }
```

Comment: Without code the answer can be rather a guessing. It is possible that one of your threads consumes all of the cache memory so the other one starves and depends on the main memory. Also the gain of multiple threads can be reduced if threads wait too long for each other to join.

Comment: @igor how can i "share" the cache memory - have each thread do a short `sleep()` once in a while?

Comment: You are almost certainly wasting cycles due to cacheline ping-pong. Both threads access the same data structures (structures describing the objects in your 3D scene, in particular). Although you do not modify the data (you may even have marked them `const`), the data structures are in read-write memory, and therefore can only be cached by one CPU core at a time. Thus, the accessed segments (cache line -sized units) ping-pong between the two cores' caches. A simple solution is to duplicate the data structures for each thread, to avoid the contention.

Comment: @nosleep This may be an option but I would not recommend it. It would need fine tuning of the sleep time which may also depend on the size of the horizontal chunk. Another possibility for the small parallel gain is if your threads have too small job to finish so the program spends most of time in creation of threads and joining them. In order to avoid this give large enough data to each thread.

Comment: Do you in fact have either multiple CPUs or a multi-core CPU (not just hyper-threading, which is one actual core pretending to be two)? If you only have a hyper-threading CPU, I'd actually be surprised to see a 20-30% gain... Also, your VM config may limit your VM to a single virtual CPU...

Comment: @NominalAnimal Since when are cache lines invalidated when *read* by another core? I admit I didn't check any ISA references, but I've read otherwise reliable material claiming that only *writing* to the cache lines causes these problems, and I have faith that CPU engineers are smart enough to optimize the common case of read-only data being shared. A quick Wikipedia search indicates that at least the MSI family of protocols accomodate this case.

Comment: @delnan: Perhaps I over-simplified. Normal reads do not invalidate cache lines, but atomic accesses via e.g. GCC `__sync_add_and_fetch(ptr,0)` do (current GCC versions lacking pure atomic fetch, i.e. `__sync_fetch(ptr)`); OP does not use locking. Also, compilers sometimes do very silly stuff: just look at the generated assembly (`gcc -S`). In any case, multiple threads using the same data is the reason why some find process-parallel implementations beat thread-parallel ones, cache effects being the root cause. Few in scientific computing understand that, and it seriously gets on my nerves.